# Twitter card not detecting urls on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter, intentfilter, twitter-card

Hi I was trying to make my android app capable of opening certain types of links posted on twitter (Twitter cards). The problem I am facing is if the link posted on twitter is http://example.com and when the parameter pathprefix is not specified in android manifest, then the button on the card displays the "open in app" text and when you click on the link it opens a dialog which has my app as one of the chooser, when the parameter pathprefix is not specified in manifest, but if the link is http://example.com/pqr and pathprefix is /pqr, then the "open in app" text is not displayed but rather "open in browser" text is displayed on the button and when I try to open the link in browser then the chooser dialog is displayed which contains my app. So, my app is capable of opening the link in app when it is opened from browser but not from the twitter card directly. I am unable to detect any flaws in the code and need help. I have written the following code in the Android manifest and the Twittercardcontent java file:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.package.TwitterCardContent"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/twittercardtitle"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/twittercardtitle">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com" android:pathPrefix="/pqr" ></data>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Activity:

```
public class TwitterCardContent extends SherlockActivity{
private WebView webview;
ActionBar actionBar;
ProgressBar aboutWebProg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
    URL url= null;
    try {
        Toast.makeText(this, uri.getScheme()+ " " +uri.getHost()+ " " +uri.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        url = new URL(uri.getScheme(), uri.getHost(), uri.getPath());
        Toast.makeText(this, url.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.twittercard);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewdata);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    aboutWebProg=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.aboutWebProg);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    /*
    webview.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    */
    //webview.setLongClickable(false);
    if (url != null)
        webview.loadUrl(url.toString());
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView  view, String  url){

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        aboutWebProg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        aboutWebProg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        aboutWebProg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share the tags from your website and the way you share it, is it via Intent or Twitter Composer?